# Why SQL Server Management Studio 2005 showing Version 2012 on running 'select @@version'

Tags: sql-server, installation

I have installed SSMS 2012 before. Now I have need to install MSS 2005 on same machine.

I need to generate backup file which will be compatible with 2005 version.

But when I run

```
select @@version
```

command in SSMS 2005 it show me version 2012.

What could be the reason?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're connecting to the SQL 2012 instance.  Your 2005 instance probably has a different instance name.  You can tell what it is if you don't remember by looking in Services and seeing what SQL instances are named there (2012 is the default, or MSSQLSERVER).  When you find the name (for example, if it's 2005), ask SSMS to connect to `.\2005` instead of what you're using.

Answer (score 0):

Management Studio is just a **client**. It *connects to* database servers. It is **not** the database itself. It is possible to install, operate, and maintain Sql Server without ever installing or using Management Studio.

What you see when selecting `@@version` is the version of the database server. It has **nothing** to do with the version of Management Studio you are using.

There is *never* a reason to need an older version of Management Studio, though you may sometimes have applications that only work with older versions of Sql Server. In many (but not all) cases, these applications can be appeased by setting the [Compatibility Level](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb510680.aspx) of the database.